# How to extend TCP Outbound gateway to just receive messages in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-integration

I am developing an web application which supports TCP connection by Spring Integration.
It has two functions.

1. send messages to Server and receive reply from Server at a time
2. just receive messages from Server

(The application on server is not developed by Spring Integration.)

In this case, TCP Adapters should be used and I need provide to collaborate TCP Outbound and Inbound Channel Adapters.
But, my application has a few restrictions.

1. this application has no database.
2. messages' payload format is already specified. (It means I can not add  any correlation data such as a transaction id to payload .

So, I think that collaborating TCP Outbound and Inbound Channel Adapters is difficult. Then, I plan to extend TCP Outbound gateway to add just receiving messages function.
How should I extend it ? (or do you have other ideas?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can determine the message type, something like this should work...

```
public class ExtendedTcpOutpboundGateway extends TcpOutboundGateway {

    private final MessageChannel unsolicitedMessageChannel;


    public ExtendedTcpOutpboundGateway(MessageChannel unsolicitedMessageChannel) {
        this.unsolicitedMessageChannel = unsolicitedMessageChannel;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMessage(Message<?> message) {
        if (isUnsolicitedMessage(message)) {
            this.messagingTemplate.send(this.unsolicitedMessageChannel, message);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return super.onMessage(message);
        }
    }

    private boolean isUnsolicitedMessage(Message<?> message) {
        // TODO Add logic here to determine message type
        return false;
    }

}
```

If you can't tell the difference, it's not clear how you could implement your requirements.

Comment: Gary Russell, Thank you very much for the answer with a good example!!!